# thread 1: “GDB:Program received signal: ”SIGABRT“.” with openears

Tags: xcode, openears

I was installed pocketsphinx on mac 10.6.8 using OpenEars with English dictionary and it working on iphone and simulator perfectly but I want to replace the dictionary from Arabic to English and when I replace the dictionary to Arabic then there is error when I run it

> thread 1: “GDB:Program received signal: ”SIGABRT“

how can I load solve it

```
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:[pronunciationDictionary substringWithRange:limitingRange]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenEars developer here. Changing the dictionary used by the LanguageModelGenerator class isn't supported and it will lead to a crash. It isn't necessary to use LanguageModelGenerator in order to do speech recognition or text to speech; it's only used for in-app dynamic language model generation in English. You can still generate language models using the CMU language tool or manually.

Comment: i made the language model manually and still the same problem

Comment: As I said, you can't change the dictionary that LanguageModelGenerator uses. If you change its dictionary as you described and then use the class, you will see that crash. If you've made a language model manually then you can stop trying to use LanguageModelGenerator, which will fix your issue.

Comment: do i need to make new LanguageModelGenerator specially to my arabic dictionary or i can use it with out the generator ?

and when i stop the class generator thats show error when run the app with arabic dic 



thread 1: “GDB:Program received signal  <<with this line>>



NSError *error = [languageModelGenerator generateLanguageModelFromArray:languageArray withFilesNamed:@"OpenEarsDynamicGrammar"];

Comment: You just can't use LanguageModelGenerator. It is currently dependent on the specific English dictionary it ships with. The crash is because you have removed a dependency of the class and you are using the class. You do not need to use LanguageModelGenerator because you have a language model. The line you have copied and posted shows that you are trying to use LanguageModelGenerator, which will not work because you have removed a file that it requires in order to be functional.

Comment: Sorry, with the time available it isn't possible for me to offer you step-by-step assistance in rewriting LanguageModelGenerator. It's well-commented so reading it should answer a lot of questions about its methods and objects, but my advice is that you find another way to accomplish your goal.